# for/in/if List Comprehension Becomes Very Slow With Large Number of Matches

Tags: python, performance, list, list-comprehension

I have the following list comprehension in my Python 2.7 code which returns the line number (index) and the line from a long list of lines:

```
results = [[lines.index(line), line] for line in lines
            if search_item in line.lower()]
```

This is lightning quick if the number of results is low:

```
The search item is: [ 1330 ]
Before string pre-processing, the time is: 0.0000
The number of lines is: 1,028,952
After string pre-processing, the time is: 0.2500
The number of results is: 249
```

"String pre-processing" is what I am calling the results = operation above.

Here is the same operation but with "1330" as the search item instead of " 1330 ". This one yields 6,049 matches instead of 249:

```
The search item is: [1330]
Before string pre-processing, the time is: 0.0000
The number of lines is: 1,028,952
After string pre-processing, the time is: 10.3180
The number of results is: 6,049
```

As you can see, 10 sec vs. 1/4 sec... Furthermore, " 1330 " and "1330" searches run in 2.4 and 3.2 sec respectively using a for loop:

```
for lineNum, line in enumerate(lines):
    if search_item in line.lower():
        return lineNum, line
```

So, list comprehension gives a 10x improvement in performance in the case of 249 results but is 3+x slower for 6,049 results...

Obviously, the issue is not in the if/in portion of list comprehension (both searches scan through all 1M+ lines and either accept or reject each one) but in constructing a results list which is "long'ish" in the second case. In other words, the bottleneck appears to be in the

```
results = [lines.index(line), line]
```

portion of the comprehension.

I guess I am very surprised that list comprehension becomes so slow for large'ish result sets (and 6K is really not that large). What am I missing? Is there a different method I should be using that would consistently outperform the for loop?

Comment: You already appear to know about `enumerate()`. Why didn't you use it in the list comprehension?

Comment: Didn't understand the overhead of list.index(). Plus, still very new to Python and, especially, to list comprehension. But, now I have a super-fast search in my app. VERY excited!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `list.index()` call has to search through *all lines* to find a match. For N lines, you execute O(N^2) steps; a 1000 lines becomes a million steps, etc. For 6k lines, that's 36 million steps <sup>*</sup>

If all you need is a line number, use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate one:

```
results = [[index, line] for index, line in enumerate(lines)
            if search_item in line.lower()]
```

`enumerate()` adds a running counter as you go, leaving your algorithm to only execute O(N) steps. You already were using this in the full `for` loop statement, but *not in your list comprehension*.

There will be a difference in the output if you have *duplicate lines* however; `lines.index()` finds the *first* match, while `enumerate()` produces unique line numbers.

---

<sup>*</sup> [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) gives us asymptotic behaviour for algorithms. Since `list.index()` for a given line *x* only has to scan (up to) *x* lines to find the index, and if you do that for each line you iterate over, you only take 1 + 2 + 3 + ... *x* steps in total, which is a [triangle number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). So in total 'only' ((N * (N + 1)) / 2) steps are taken, roughtly 1/2 N^2 steps. But when N tends to infinity, multipliers no longer matter, and you end up with O(N^2).

Comment: Yeah, but when are we ever going to actually use big-O professor?

Comment: @JeremyWest: all the time. Because it matters here.

Comment: Agreed. That was the joke.

Comment: Martijn, THANK YOU! Now runs in 0.3 sec with 6K results! Very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Tried to accept it right away, but seems there is a 10 or 15 min or so timer before I could. May be a noob thing... Thank you again!!!

Comment: @JeremyWest: sorry to have killed it so!

Comment: Kind of nitpicky, but 1k lines is more like 500k steps and 6k lines is more like 18m steps, but explaining that would probably distract from the answer.

Comment: @JaredGoguen: yes, it is the sum of the triangle number of N plus N, so N + ((N * (N + 1)) / 2), roughly N + 1/2 N^2. Asymptotically speaking, that's *basically* N^2 anyway.